# How to loop through immutable and push it to array Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, iteration, immutable.js

I have my form field values in an immutable object.
I use `getIn` immutable function to access it.

For example, if I have to access field, i use `const users = formFields.getIn(['0', value])`.
Now, i have a variable

> users = 4`

This means, there will be 4 fields in immutable from which i need to pick up the users age.

e.g.

- 1st user age will be stored in `formFields.getIn(['1', value])`
- 2nd user age will be stored in `formFields.getIn(['2', value])`
- and so on

How do i loop through the user age list based on the users variable?
I tried something like this:

```
const userAgeList = [];
if (users >0) {
  userAgeList.push(formFields.getIn([[i], value]));
}
```

With above code `formFields.getIn([[i], value])`, i get undefined because the value is not actually on this. its on `formFields.getIn(['i', value])`.

How do i pass the loop variable i as a string so i can get the field values?

Comment: `[i]` this makes an array with one value, the value of `i`. Is this what you're expecting?

Comment: Have you tried to use template strings? Like ` ${i} ` ?

Comment: @evolutionxbox- if i just use i, it will be number. i want to use 'i'

Comment: @ashwinprabhu, Did you tried like, ```formFields.getIn([`${i}`, value])``` ??

Comment: `formFields.getIn([i.toString(), value])`?

Comment: Maniraj is likely correct. Native arrays and objects auto-convert the type of a key in certain cases, but immutablejs will not. So number 1 is not the same as string '1'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If what you have is a [`List`](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List) containing [`Map`](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/Map) objects, you can use a `map` to loop all the values:

```
const userAgeList = formFields
  .map(field -> field.get('value'))
  .toArray()
```

This will give you an array of the values you need.
If you want to take only at a specific `i`, **convert it to a number** and then you can combine [skip](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/skip) and [take](https://immutable-js.github.io/immutable-js/docs/#/List/take) in this fashion:

```
const userAgeList = formFields
  .skip(i)
  .take(1)
  .map(field -> field.get('value'))
  .toArray()
```

This will return you a one element array at the `i` position.